# Drawing only three quarters of a brace using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw just three quarters of a brace to illustrate that the brace is going on (see my example below, the brace with caption `e`). I want to illustrate that the section (marked by the brace with caption `e`) goes to infinity on the left.

```
\documentclass[11pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=brace]%, scale=0.85]
\draw [black,ultra thick](0,0)--(10,0);
\draw [BrickRed,ultra thick, dashed](-2,0)--(0,0);
\draw [BrickRed,ultra thick, dashed](10,0)--(12,0);
\draw [black,ultra thick](10,-0.2)--(10,0.2);
\draw [black,ultra thick](0,-0.2)--(0,0.2);

\draw[MidnightBlue, thick,decorate, yshift=2ex] (0.0,0) -- node[above=0.4ex] {a} (2,0);
\draw[MidnightBlue, thick,decorate, yshift=-2ex] (3.2,0) -- node[below=0.4ex] {b} (2,0);
\draw[MidnightBlue, thick,decorate, yshift=2ex] (3.2,0) -- node[above=0.4ex] {c} (6,0);
\draw[MidnightBlue, thick,decorate, yshift=-2ex] (10,0) -- node[below=0.4ex] {d} (6,0);
\draw[MidnightBlue, thick,decorate, yshift=-2ex] (0,0) -- node[below=0.4ex] {e} (-2,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please complete the [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: What do you want exactly? Header? Reduced example?

Comment: Please, read [this guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to understand what I mean. If you provide a complete MWE you probably get help more effectively and quickly. ;)

Comment: Here you are. The code will now give you exactly the result which is shown in the attached picture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I copied the definition of the `brace` decoration and modified it a bit to have an extra property which determines on which side the brace is open.

The `open brace` decoration has the extra key `open=<side>`.  It defaults to `none` which is equivalent to the normal `brace`.  Possible options are:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newif\ifopenbraceleft
\newif\ifopenbraceright
\openbraceleftfalse
\openbracerightfalse

\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/decoration/.cd,
  open/.is choice,
  open/left/.is if = openbraceleft,
  open/right/.is if = openbraceright,
  open/both/.style = {open/left = true, open/right = true},
  open/none/.style = {open/left = false, open/right = false},
  open/.initial = none
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{open brace}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=+\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance,next state=final]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \ifopenbraceright
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    \else
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfqpoint{.15\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.3\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    {\pgfqpoint{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    \fi
    {
      \pgftransformxshift{+\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      \pgfpathcurveto
      {\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      {\pgfqpoint{-.15\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.7\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      {\pgfqpoint{0\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{1\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      \pgfpathcurveto
      {\pgfqpoint{.15\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.7\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      {\pgfqpoint{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    }
    {
      \pgftransformxshift{+\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance}
      \ifopenbraceleft
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      \else
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      \pgfpathcurveto
      {\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      {\pgfqpoint{-.15\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}{.3\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
      {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
      \fi
    }
  }
  \state{final}
  {}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [black,ultra thick](0,0)--(10,0);
\draw [BrickRed,ultra thick, dashed](-2,0)--(0,0);
\draw [BrickRed,ultra thick, dashed](10,0)--(12,0);
\draw [black,ultra thick](10,-0.2)--(10,0.2);
\draw [black,ultra thick](0,-0.2)--(0,0.2);

\draw[MidnightBlue,thick,decorate,decoration=brace,yshift=2ex] (0.0,0) -- node[above=0.4ex] {a} (2,0);
\draw[MidnightBlue,thick,decorate,decoration=brace,yshift=-2ex] (3.2,0) -- node[below=0.4ex] {b} (2,0);
\draw[MidnightBlue,thick,decorate,decoration=brace,yshift=2ex] (3.2,0) -- node[above=0.4ex] {c} (6,0);
\draw[MidnightBlue,thick,decorate,decoration=brace,yshift=-2ex] (10,0) -- node[below=0.4ex] {d} (6,0);
\draw[MidnightBlue,thick,decorate,decoration={open brace,open=left},yshift=-2ex] (0,0) -- node[below=0.4ex] {e} (-2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]